# Variance of a function of independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, order-statistics, covariance

Suppose I have two discrete independant random variables $X$ and $Y$, and that I'm interested in the expected value of the random variable $W$, where:
$$
W= \text{sign}(X-Y).
$$
So, W is 1 if $X>Y$, -1 if $Y>X$ and 0 otherwise.

I sample the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ ten times each, giving me $\{X_1, \dots, X_{10}\}$ and $\{Y_1, \dots, Y_{10}\}$.
Consider these two ways to estimate $\text{E}\{W\}$
$$
\quad\quad\bar{W} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10} W_{i,i}, \\
\text{and, } \quad\quad
\bar{W}' = \frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10} W_{i,j}, \\
\text{where } \quad W_{i,j} = \text{sign}(X_i - Y_j)
$$
I know that $\text{Var}\{\bar{W}\} = \frac{1}{10}\text{Var}\{W\}$, but what is $\text{Var}\{\bar{W}'\}$, and how can I estimate it from my 20 samples?

Comment: I have shown my work as an attempted answer.  Since I am now opening a bounty, if you have a substancial add, please make a new, self-contained answer, so that you would be eligible for the bounty!

Comment: Duplicate of:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/variance-of-sample-mean-for-dependent-samples  ... by same author

Comment: @wolfies: this one is the original.  Until a few hours ago it had been several days with a bounty and no answer, so I tried CrossVal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\sign{\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}}
\def\Cov{\mathop{\mathrm{Cov}}}
$You have an empirical distribution $P$ of $X$ and $Y$, with the probability mass function
$p(x,y)=\frac1{mn}\sum_{i,j}[x=x_i][y=y_j]$, and your estimate of
$\mathbb{E}[\sign(X-Y)]$ is
$$ \mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y)] = \frac1{mn}\sum_{i,j}\sign(x_i-y_j) =
\bar W'. $$

You can calculate an estimate of variance in exactly the same way as
$$ \mathbb{V}^P[\sign(X-Y)] = \mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y)^2] -
(\mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y)])^2. $$
Since $\sign(a)^2=1$ when $a\neq0$, the first expectation is
$$ Q = \mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y)^2] = \mathbb{P}^P[X\neq Y] =
\frac1{mn}\sum_{i,j}[x_i\neq y_j]. $$
So the sample variance is
$$ \mathbb{V}^P[\sign(X-Y)] = Q-(\bar W')^2. $$

The variance of $\bar W'$ is calculated in the same way. Under the
true probability distribution we have
$$ \mathbb{V}\left[\frac1{mn}\sum_{i,j}\sign(x_i-x_j)\right] =
\frac1{mn}\mathbb{V}[\sign(X-Y)] +
\frac1{m^2n^2}\sum_{(i,j)\neq(k,l)}\Cov(W_{ij},W_{kl}). $$
The covariance between $W_{ij}$ and $W_{kl}$ is zero when $i\neq k$
and $k\neq l$, so the only nonzero covariances are
$Q_X = \Cov(W_{ij},W_{il})$ and $Q_Y = \Cov(W_{ij},W_{kj})$, and both
of these are independent of the indices. Therefore if we let
$X,X_1,X_2$ and $Y,Y_1,Y_2$ be independent copies of $X$ and $Y$, then
$$ Q_X = \Cov(\sign(X-Y_1),\sign(X-Y_2)), \qquad Q_Y =
\Cov(\sign(X_1-Y),\sign(X_2-Y)), $$
and the variance of $\bar W'$ is
$$ \mathbb{V}[\bar W'] = \frac1{mn}\mathbb{V}[\sign(X-Y)] + \frac{n-1}{mn}Q_X +
\frac{m-1}{mn}Q_Y. $$

You can calculate these terms as expectations under the empirical
distribution, so $Q_X$ for example, becomes:
$$ \begin{aligned}
Q_X &= \mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y_1)^2\sign(X-Y_2)^2] - \mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y_1)]\mathbb{E}^P[\sign(X-Y_2)]
\\&= \frac1{mn^2}\sum_{i,j,k}[x_i\neq y_j, x_i\neq y_k] -
\left( \frac1{mn}\sum_{i,j}\sign(x_i-y_j)\right)^2. 
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer.  So that tells me $\mathbb{V}^P[sign(X-Y)]$.  But what is $\mathbb{V}^P\{\bar{W}'\}$?

Comment: @EdwardNewell I edited the answer to illustrate, but this is pretty close to what you said in your answer. What is the source of your confusion about this question?

Comment: Ok, I see that you've illustrated $\mathbb{V}^P\{\bar{W}'\}$ now.  That *does* involve more than what is entailed in calculating $\mathbb{V}^P[\text{sign}(X-Y)]$, since covariances come up.  

You're following my method, although you are getting different coefficients.  I'm not totally reassured! I get $1/100$ in front of $\mathbb{V}\{W\}$ and my coefficient for $Q_X$ is 9/200, which is twice yours.  I get 9/200 because we start with a coefficient of 1/10000, and there are ${10 \choose 2 }$ cases of $Q_X$ per row, with 10 rows, so 450 in total, and $450 / 10000 = 9/200$.

Comment: @EdwardNewell You're right: I was missing $\frac1{mn}$. The sum $\sum_{(i,j)\neq(k,l)}$ decomposes as $$\sum_{(i,j)\neq(k,l)} = \sum_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=i,l\neq j}+\sum_{l=j,k\neq i}\right)$$, so there are $(m-1)mn$ and $(n-1)mn$ terms of each type, respectively. So that part looks right to me.

Comment: Ok, yeah that's right.  For some reason I thought that one shouldn't count $\text{Cov}\{A_i,A_j\}$ *and* $\text{Cov}\{A_j,A_i\}$, so I was off by a factor of 2.  So, I think we have the right answer then!

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic formula for the variance of a sum of random variables.  For some random variables $A_i$, this can be stated as:
$$
\text{Var}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right\} = \sum_{i=1}^n\text{Var}\{A_i\} + \sum_{i \neq j} \text{Cov}\{A_i,A_j\} \\
$$
In this case, we get:
$$ 
\text{Var}\{\bar{W}'\} = \text{Var}\left\{\frac{1}{100}\sum_{k\in \{1,...,10\}^2}W_{k}\right\} \\
= \frac{1}{10000}\left(\sum_{k \in \{1,...,10\}^2}\text{Var}\{W_k\} +  \sum_{k,\ell \in \{1,...,10\}^2; k\neq \ell}\text{Cov}\{W_k,W_\ell\}\right)
$$
Note that above, the subscripts $k$ and $\ell$ represent pairs, i.e. $k= (i,j)$, which I'm using because the notation for the indices gets too complicated otherwise!

The trick is that $\text{Cov}\{W_k, W_\ell\}$ is not zero if one of the indicies is the same.  This can happen in two different ways.  Either the first index is the same ---  $k = (i,j)$ and $\ell = (i,m)$ --- or the second index is the same --- $k = (i,j)$ and $\ell=(m,j)$.  Otherwise $W_k$ and $W_j$ are based on different, and independent samples, and so are independent.

Therefore, you need to estimate $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{i,m}\}$ and $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{m,j}\}$.
Note that it doesn't matter what the specific indices are --- all that matters is which of the indices are shared.  (this is because all $X_i$'s are i.i.d, and all $Y_i$'s are too.)

You could estimate $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{i,m}\}$ using your samples by calculating $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,1}, W_{i,2}\}$:

$$
\text{Cov}\{W_{i,1}, W_{i,2}\} = \frac{1}{9}\sum_{i\in\{1,...,10\}}\left(W_{i,1} - \text{E}\{W_{\cdot,1}\}\right)\left(W_{i,2} - \text{E}\{W_{\cdot,2}\}\right)
$$

You could also calculate $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,3},W_{i,4}\}$ from your samples.  Both $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,1}, W_{i,2}\}$, and $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,3},W_{i,4}\}$ provide independent estimates of $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{i,m}\}$.  You can refine your estimate of $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{i,m}\}$ by taking the mean of various independent estimators.  But be careful not to also include something like $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,2},W_{i,3}\}$ along with the others already mentioned, since it would not be independent from them.

Then, do similarly to estimate $\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{m,j}\}$.  For example:
$$
\text{Cov}\{W_{1,j}, W_{2,j}\} = \frac{1}{9}\sum_{j\in\{1,...,10\}}\left(W_{1,j} - \text{E}\{W_{1,\cdot}\}\right)\left(W_{2,j} - \text{E}\{W_{2,\cdot}\}\right)
$$

To take the sum of the covariances, note that each of these *types* of covariance term arises $10\times 10\times 900$ times so, for your particular shape of sample sets,

$$
\text{Var}\{\bar{W}'\} = \frac{\text{Var}\{W_k\}}{100} +  \frac{9}{100}\left(\text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{i,m}\} + \text{Cov}\{W_{i,j},W_{m,j}\}\right) 
$$

Comment: This is my best answer based on the research I've done.  I don't feel confident enough to accept it though -- I would really appreciate if someone who has a deep grasp could sanity-check this!

Comment: Instead of 9/100 in the last line, I had originally 9/200.  This was corrected after reading Kirill's answer and discussing.